# Is it possible to approximate the natural logarithm by integrating $x^n$ with respect to $x$, where $n \approx -1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, approximation

In general,

$$
\int x^{n} dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C
$$

However, this rule does not work when $n=-1$ because it leads to division by zero. Instead, $\int x^{-1} dx = \ln(|x|) + C$. This standard result made me wonder if the natural logarithm could be approximated by using $n$-values that are close to, but not equal to, $-1$. For example, setting n  as equal to $-0.99$:

$$
\int x^{-0.99} dx = \frac{x^{0.01}}{0.01} +C = 100x^{0.01}+C
$$

The $C$ value that translated the graph so that it became a good approximation was $-100$. Here is the general case. My suspicion is that as $k$ tends to infinity, the approximation becomes better and better:

$$
\int x^{-1+1/k} dx = \frac{x^{1/k}}{1/k}+C=kx^{1/k}+C
$$

Using $-k$ as the constant of integration, I produced the following result:

[image]

As you can see, it is difficult to see any difference between the two graphs. I have two questions:

1. Why does $C$ have to equal $-k$ in order for the approximation to work?
2. Can this approach be formalised by using limits? E.g. as $k \to \infty$, $kx^{1/k}-k$ becomes arbitrarily close to $\ln(x)$?

Comment: In short, yes. This is one way to define the logarithm. Great question

Comment: More precisely, $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} d t$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the function
$$f(a)=\int_1^xt^a\,dt=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^{a+1}-1}{a+1} & a\ne -1 \\
\log(x) & a=-1
\end{cases} $$
(where $x>0$) and show that $f$ is continuous at $a=-1$. Using
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=1 $$
we have
$$\lim_{a\to -1}\frac{x^{a+1}-1}{a+1}=\lim_{a\to -1}\left(\frac{e^{\log(x)(a+1)}-1}{\log(x)(a+1)}\cdot\log(x)\right)=\log(x) $$
So you can approximate the graph of $\log(x)$ by taking $a$ to be close to $-1$, as you've done in your plot.